# Function redeclare fatal error?

Tags: php, function

I have declared a function `log()` just once (according to me) in a file **function.php** and the file is included using `require_once`. So why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP already has a built-in [`log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php) function, for finding the natural logarithm of a number.

You cannot define new functions with the same name as built-in functions. You'll have to call your function something else.